# Subgroups of GL_2 over a finite field

Tags: gr.group-theory, reference-request, rt.representation-theory

I've come across the phrase "by the classification of subgroups of $GL_2(F_q)$" in multiple papers, but never with a reference.  Here $F_q$ is a finite field of size $q$.  Does anyone know a good reference for this (ideally for someone who is not a group theorist)?

Comment: I think the classification is Borel, (Split or nonsplit) Cartan, or the ``exceptionals'', which are projectively $A_4$, $A_5$, $S_4$. See Lang or Serre for more details. 

Comment: Barinder, it's more complicated than that: $GL_2(\mathbb F_p)$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb F_q)$ is $q=p^e$ which your classification forgets, for example.

Answer (score 4):

At the text-book level, take a look at Lang's Algebra, Chapter XVIII, Section 12, in my version is on page 712. Seems to be pretty thorough.

There is also section 2 of Serre's 1972 ``Propriétés galoisiennes des points d'ordre fini des courbes elliptiques''.

Comment: Barinder, this answer is not really helpful. Serre's section 2 is titled "Sous-groupe de $GL_2(\mathbb F_p)$", not $\mathbb F_q", and Lang is far from thorough on this question.

Answer (score 4):

Dickson is responsible for the classification of subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ (and once you've got this the subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ are easy). You can find a full proof in Suzuki's "Group Theory Part I". It's Chapter 6, Section 3 of that book. If you email me I'll even send you a copy :-)

Answer (score 2):

This classification was well-known already in the beginning of XXth century; perhaps this explains why people do not bother to give a reference (the result was due to E.H.Moore and, independently, Wiman).

Many years ago I read the paper by Howard H. Mitchell, 
[Determination of the ordinary and modular ternary linear groups.](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1911-012-02/S0002-9947-1911-1500887-3/home.html) 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 12 (1911), no. 2, 207–242, which addresses the analogous question for $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$, and also contains the detailed information on the subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. (It's of course not so easy to read, as the terminology was quite different...)